# Convert QTextCharFormat to QJsonValue

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qjson

I have to convert a QTextCharFormat to a QJsonValue because it has to be transmitted from a client to a server in a Json message, but I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If its a qtquick app you can use javascript function between the qml code and get the returned json var from the js function.

Convert QtextCharFormat to a char and then pass it to js function.